# App Crashes on test flight after installing due to CoreData Migration

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an older version of my app on testflight. I added 2 entities to coreData and I was not familiar with the migration requirements. Now my app crashes with the following error on the piece of code I attached

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "LocalDatabase")
    /*add necessary support for migration*/
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions =  [description]
        /*add necessary support for migration*/
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

The Crash occurs at second line. The app isn't live yet, so it is a possibility for me to make sure that I perform the migration next time I make a change to core Data. But is there something I can do now to resolve this issue.

I don't get an explicit error when I try to build directly on device. It just gives the unable to install error
[image: Crash logs]

Comment: “…with the following error”, it’s not clear to me what that error is. Could you include the actual error message or clarify it if it’s already included?

Comment: This is the problem. I am unable to get an error. App doesn't build directly on device and this is the crash report from testflight

Comment: What do you mean the app doesn't build directly on a device? How are you testing it before going to TestFlight?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have older versions on testflight. version 11 had some changes in Coredata. So, if we install 12,13 or 14 on top of 11, it keeps working but when I install 12,13 or 14 on 10, it crashes.

Comment: I identified the issue. It was due to migration failing. It was failing because I had no change in the CoreData. So, I just added a dummy entity